# SharePoint File is being downloaded instead of being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I got an ASPX file on my Sharepoint. It's supposed to display some simple tables after clicking on it, but instead of it, it's being downloaded to my PC. 
There is another file like that in my other folder and it works perfectly fine.
Could anyone give me some advice, how could I fix this problem, please?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If the Aspx file is located in Site Pages or Pages library, it should display data directly rather than download if clicking it.

For this issue I suggest you can create a new site page and insert your custom JavaScript logic into the new created page, it should be able to display directly.